# Google sheets: is it possible to protect a range of cell such that it can only be modify with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have a shared google sheet that enters date and time when a button is push.  However, once enter I do not want the user to be able to modify the date.  I know I can protect a range of cells but in this case I still need the macro/script to be able to enter the time.

Is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: For example, in your situation, there are you (owner of Spreadsheet) and users. The users run the script by clicking a button and the script puts the date value to a cell. At this time, you want to have already protected the cells for putting the date value from the users. But, when the users click the button, you want to put the date values to the protected cells. Is my understanding correct? In this case, I think that Google Apps Script is required to be used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike yes this is correct, however I'm confused because would the script have the same permission as the person clicking the button?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- There are you (owner of Spreadsheet) and users.
- Users run the script by clicking a button and the script puts the date value to a cell. At this time, you want to have already protected the cells for putting the date value from the users.
- But, when the users click the button, you want to put the date values to the protected cells.
- In your situation, Google Apps Script can be used.

From [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020192/google-sheets-is-it-possible-to-protect-a-range-of-cell-such-that-it-can-only-b#comment116728949_66020192), I could confirm my understanding is correct.

### Issue and workaround:

When the script is run by clicking a button on Google Spreadsheet, the script is run as the user who clicked the button. So the authorization for scopes is required to be done as the users. I thought that this might be the answer of your replying `I'm confused because would the script have the same permission as the person clicking the button?`.

Under this situation, when the script puts a value to the cell protected by the owner, an error like `You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.` occurs. So in order to avoid this error, it is considered that when the script is run as the owner, the issue will be avoided.

In this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. This workaround is as follows.

When the user runs the script by clicking a button on Spreadsheet, it runs the script as the owner by using Web Apps. When this workaround is used, please do the following flow.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare Spreadsheet.

Please create new Spreadsheet and create a button and assign the function of `runWithWorkaround` to the button. And, please protect the cell "A1" as the user of only owner. In this sample, the target cell is "A1".

#### 2. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name which has the button.

```
// This function puts a date to cell "A1".
function putValue() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());
}

// This function is for Web Apps.
function doGet() {
  putValue();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}

// This function is used for testing "without using this workaround.".
function runWithoutWorkaround() {
  putValue();
}

// This function is used for testing "with using this workaround.".
function runWithWorkaround() {
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please replace this URL with your Web Apps URL.
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" for using Web Apps.
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detail information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the important of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone with Google account "** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is required to use the access token for requesting to Web Apps.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. When "The Web App requires you to authorize access to your data" is shown, please click "Authorize access".
8. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Select own account.
   2. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   3. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   4. Click "Allow" button.
9. Copy the URL of Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
10. **Copy and paste the retrieved Web Apps URL to the above script.**
11. **Because the script of Web Apps is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps.**

#### 4. Testing.

When above workaround is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- When several users use the button simultaneously, to use the lock service might be suitable. When the lock service is used, the function `runWithWorkaround` is as follows.

  ```
    function runWithWorkaround() {
      var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
      if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
        try {
          const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
          UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
        } catch(e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        } finally {
          lock.releaseLock();
        }
      }
      // DriveApp.getFiles() // This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope for using Web Apps.
    }
  ```
- Above sample script is the simple sample script for explaining the methodology of this workaround. Please be careful this. So if you use this workaround, please modify your actual script using this workaround.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: that is incredible thank you for your help in this. I did not think this would had been possible given the catch 22 in permission.

Comment: @Ahdee Thank you for replying. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.