# How i use app script to edit google sheets protected range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can i know did apps script can do it even the range already protected but when click a button run script will add value into the protected range?
[image: Example1]

[image: Script]

I want the result look like after i click the button insert data will show **Data1** at protected range there.
[image: Example2]

Comment: Protected Cells are meant to protect the cells being edited by the people who have no access to certain cells. There is a certain authority level in terms of making what you want happen depending on your use case. I presume that you are looking to insert a definite value on a sheet when the button is clicked. If this was the case does Web Apps suits your needs better?

Comment: I apologize for the spam, and can you clarify your use case scenario for your project so that the community has a better chance of providing a workaround or even better an answer for you. Are you looking to share the editing capability on some of the users? Or are you trying to let your user edit something on your sheet and when the button is clicked the user will save it on protected cells so that it cannot be edited in any way?

Comment: @Babanana I found a solution for using deploy as WebApp (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020192/google-sheets-is-it-possible-to-protect-a-range-of-cell-such-that-it-can-only-b?rq=4) but it work will one insert, how can be i want two different insert? This was my testing file 【https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-Z_q0FgjMdWR7XBFO0WwmyLB8aqeaklGdWeL4G9odQ/edit#gid=0】

Comment: I do apologize for the confusion about your additional question. I understand you are looking for different 2 function to access the Web App, instead of providing 2 values at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changing the Script to call 2 Different Functions:

I do apologize for the previous confusion here is the updated code that suits your needs better:

### Code Modification:

```
// This is your basic Spreadsheet Changes Functions
function addData1() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('List');
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();

  if (sheet1.getRange("B2").getValues() == "") {
    sheet1.getRange(2, 6, 1, 1).setValue("Data1");
  }
  else {
    sheet1.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6, 1, 1).setValue("Data1");
  }
}
function addData2() {

  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('List');
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();

  if (sheet1.getRange("B2").getValues() == "") {
    sheet1.getRange(2, 7, 1, 1).setValue("Data2");
  }
  else {
    sheet1.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7, 1, 1).setValue("Data2");
  }
}
function doGet(e) {
  var buttonClicked = e.parameter.buttonClicked;
  if (buttonClicked === "addData1") {
    return addData1();

  }
  else if (buttonClicked === "addData2") {
    return addData2();
  }
}
//Please change accordingly to your WebApps URL and the "e.parameter.buttonClicked;"
function button1() {

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzz6w7PVjNLuz1NR6ZPAmNnRpbF17AES-B8qlELOZHlzxNrKRcJupXcM3UgtWOTce59/exec?buttonClicked=addData1");
}
function button2() {

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzz6w7PVjNLuz1NR6ZPAmNnRpbF17AES-B8qlELOZHlzxNrKRcJupXcM3UgtWOTce59/exec?buttonClicked=addData2");
}
```

*Note: As this is working with Web Apps that there could be delays on Data writing depending on how often a request is pass through the Web App Macro*

### Sample:

[image]

### Reference:

[Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Ya this is actually what I want, thanks for the solutions